# Display data from multiple tables using mySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a simple mysql database and am working with PHP to display results for individually selected items from a table. I can't get individual selections to show.  My code is below.  It seems that something is not triggering for the .$selectedbow but I don't know how to get it right.  Be gentle - I'm totally new to this.  Thank you!

```
$bowinfo = mysql_query("SELECT id, make, description 
                        FROM bowid WHERE bowid=".$selectedbow);

        //START THE WHILE LOOP 
        while ($bowdata = mysql_fetch_array($bowinfo)) {

            $id = $bowinfo["id"];
            $make = $bowinfo["make"];
            $description - $bowinfo["description"];

    echo ( "<section>
                    <p> $id</p> 
                    <p>$make</p>
                    <p>$description</p></section>
                    ");
```

Comment: *"to display results from 3 different tables"* - What three tables? http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ - You're also referencing the wrong variable.

Comment: The answer you've gotten below; does it not solve the problem you're having?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I corrected the code and still nothing displays?  http://confessionsofaclosethipster.com/bowdescription_detail.php

Comment: That site's not loading. It times out.

Comment: interesting......it loads fine for me.  But, to describe what it does, I have the echo statement which shows the html entered, but nothing is coming in from the db. So something is still not connecting with the while loop

Comment: So, where's `$selectedbow` coming from? I take it that's an integer and not a string. Plus, what version of PHP are you running off from?

Comment: Attempting PHP5, I'm working with W3Schools to try to figure it out.  $selectedbow is a variable that pulls from the link in the landing page I created with PHP and mySQL query for the bow name.

Comment: You didn't quite answer my question; integer or string? Give me an example `123`? `www.site.xxx`? other?. My guess is that you've got errors and are not using error checking for both PHP and MySQL. Do that and you'll get your answer. I hope you're not mixin MySQL APIs neither. Too many things can go wrong. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php - Plus, PHP 5 has many version. 5.2? 5.3? 5.4? 5.5? other?

Comment: It's a string.  I'm  not mixing mysql api's, no api (that I know of) is involved.  merely trying to get an individual view from a table.  I wish I could explain better, but I just don't know how to explain it better because I'm so new to this :(

Comment: If it's a string, you need to do `WHERE bowid='$selectedbow'");` Here: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and you'll see just what it is I mean by errors. As for the API; you have to use one. You are connecting to DB somehow, correct? It's not shown in your question.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Ohhh... CPanel is what I'm using, sorry.

Comment: I don't use CPanel to execute MySQL, so I won't be able to help you out there. Run it from the WWW instead. Either way, I'm sure there are errors, you're just not letting PHP/MySQL show you what they are, as outlined earlier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the code within your `while` loop, you should be using `$bowdata` not `$bowinfo`, ie.:

```
$id = $bowdata["id"];
$make = $bowdata["make"];
$description = $bowdata["description"];
```

and to get data from multiple tables you can do SQL joins, for that I need to know other tables detail

Comment: What detail do you need to know?  I may have misspoke.  I have one table I'm trying to pull this information from.  The table contains an ID, Make, and Description of a bow.  I really only want to display the Make and the Description of each bow individually one on its own page.

Comment: if there are not multiple tables, no problem,

Comment: gotcha.  sorry :(  I'm just so lost LOL